# pymssql, can't execute EXEC command sql

Tags: python, sql, pymssql

i'm trying to execute this type of sql command with python but that doesn't work

```
import pymssql

_conn = pymssql.connect(** SQL parameter)
_cur = _conn.cursor()
_cur.execute("EXEC(SELECT * something)")
```

i got this error.

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I update the post

Comment: Did you try adding `_conn.commit()` after the line of `_cur.execute(...` ?

Comment: yeap that doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

The EXECUTE command takes a string, not plain SQL commands:

```
EXEC('SELECT * something')
```

But I'm not sure why you're doing this, you could just pass the SELECT statement directly.

Comment: Because i have to read an sql file that have this type of sql request

Comment: I don't understand. Show the contents of that SQL file and the full code you're using to read it.

Comment: See the next answer